# TF model not minimizing loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have coded the following model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mod_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))
mod = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, "selu")(mod_input)
mod = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, "selu")(mod)
mod = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, "selu")(mod)
pre_mu = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, "selu")(mod)
mu = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, "linear")(pre_mu)
model = tf.keras.Model(mod_input, mu, name="model")

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = model

    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean = self.model(x)
            # MSE
            total_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(
                tf.math.square(z_mean - y)
            )
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
        }
```

Which on my experience, should minimize (it's an example) the MSE... however, it's not, infact, compiling it with:

```
mm = MyModel(model)
mm.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
history = mm.fit(x, y_noised, epochs=80, batch_size=1000)
```

I get the last loss to be 888.2213... however, with the following model, the last loss is 31.8990:

```
m = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="selu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="selu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="selu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")
])
```

what am I missing?

BTW, If instead of compiling `mm` I compile `mod`, it works fine:

```
mm = MyModel(model)
mod.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
history = mod.fit(x, y_noised, epochs=80, batch_size=1000)
```

(ignoring `mm`)

Answer (score 0):

Caught the problem...

In the `train_step`, `y` had shape `(1000,)` and `z_mean` `(1000,1)`, so the `-` operator was returning a matrix with a pairwise distance (every possible pair), not a "couple" distance (first with first, second with second...)